# How can I fix bottom navigation hides the parent fragment bottom content on backbutton pressed?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have main activity with 5 bottom navigation options. I placed a fragment inside activity.  Whenever I return from its child fragment, this fragment’s content goes behind bottom navigation view. How can I fix this?

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="com.work.workapp.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

newsfeed.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_feed_post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

recyclerview_single_element

```
<LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <!-- view button -->
            <FrameLayout>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center|fill_horizontal" />
            </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

button_click event from recyclerview adapter

```
myViewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                OpenPost op = new OpenPost();
                FragmentTransaction ft = ((AppCompatActivity)view.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, op, "").addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Add xml files, please.

Comment: can you please add the xml files on your question

Comment: question updated